# Криптоанализ простой перестановкой

Tags: c#, алгоритм, криптография

Мой набор данных:

`39 25 20 34 82 63 66 46 35 20 25 82 86 39 51 74 35 51 66 20 44 37 25 27 51 35 44 20 90 37 51 25 25 51 63 91 20 11 37 46 48 25 20 37 61 51 14 82 82 66 82 35 29 82 91 25 51 74 51 24 78 51 24 59 46 86 51 44 74 20 25 37 37, 37 44 82 31 11 37 82 51 46 25 51 34 82 25 37 82 86 37 25 27 51 35 44 20 90 37 51 25 25 48 44 46 82 78 25 51 14 51 18 37 59 44, 51 74 82 35 20 90 37 59 44 66 90 82 25 25 48 44 37 61 10 44 20 18 20 44 37, 86 61 20 25 86 51 39 66 86 51 44 10 66 82 86 46 51 35 10 37 66 51 46 51 39 51 63 66 39 59 91 37. 56 46 51 86 20 66 20 82 46 66 59 24 35 10 18 37 78 51 35 18 20 25 37 91 20 90 37 63, 4651, 66 51 18 14 20 66 25 51 35 82 91 10 14 29 46 20 46 20 44 35 20 91 14 37 56 25 48 78 37 66 66 14 82 24 51 39 20 25 37 63, 35 10 86 51 39 51 24 37 46 82 14 37 44 25 51 18 37 78 3791 25 37 78 91 25 20 31 46 51 61 51 66 25 51 39 25 48 78 39 37 24 20 78 10 18 35 51 91, 25 51 25 82 10 24 82 14 59 31 46 24 51 14 42 25 51 18 51 39 25 37 44 20 25 37 59 24 20 25 25 48 44 39 51 74 35 51 66 20 44, 66 56 37 46 20 59, 56 46 51 51 61 82 66 74 82 56 82 25 37 82 37 25 27 51 35 44 20 90 37 51 25 25 51 63 61 82 91 51 74 20 66 25 51 66 46 37 25 82 37 44 82 82 46 66 44 48 66 14 20, 82 66 14 37 51 46 66 10 46 66 46 39 10 82 46 39 37 24 37 44 20 59 10 18 35 51 91 20.`

Код:

```
private static Dictionary<string, double> symbols = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    ["О"] = 0.090,
    ["Е"] = 0.072,
    ["А"] = 0.062,
    ["И"] = 0.062,
    ["Т"] = 0.053,
    ["Н"] = 0.053,
    ["С"] = 0.045,
    ["Р"] = 0.040,
    ["В"] = 0.038,
    ["Л"] = 0.035,
    ["К"] = 0.028,
    ["М"] = 0.026,
    ["Д"] = 0.025,
    ["П"] = 0.023,
    ["У"] = 0.021,
    ["Я"] = 0.018,
    ["Ы"] = 0.016,
    ["З"] = 0.016,
    ["Ь"] = 0.014,
    ["Б"] = 0.014,
    ["Г"] = 0.013,
    ["Ч"] = 0.012,
    ["Й"] = 0.010,
    ["Х"] = 0.009,
    ["Ж"] = 0.007,
    ["Ю"] = 0.006,
    ["Ш"] = 0.006,
    ["Ц"] = 0.004,
    ["Щ"] = 0.003,
    ["Э"] = 0.003,
    ["Ф"] = 0.002
};

private static string Decrypt(string encryptText)
{
    string result = null;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptText)) return result;
    var temp = encryptText.Split(' ');
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (string s in temp)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            dict.Add(s, 0);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        dict[temp[i]]++;
    }

    var myList = dict.ToList();
    myList.Sort((pair1, pair2) => pair2.Value.CompareTo(pair1.Value));

    Console.WriteLine($"Encrypt text:\n{encryptText}\n");

    Console.WriteLine($"Symbols count - {temp.Length}");

    foreach (var kv in myList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} - {Math.Round((double)kv.Value / temp.Length, 4)} ({kv.Value})");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    result = encryptText;

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        var symbol = symbols.ElementAt(i);

        result = result.Replace(myList[i].Key, symbol.Key);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Decrypt text:\n{result}");

    return result;
}
```

Проблема: Выдаёт ошибку в цикле ниже на 31 итерации

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        var symbol = symbols.ElementAt(i);

        result = result.Replace(myList[i].Key, symbol.Key);
    }
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или **ошибку** и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Какую ошибку? Как этот код запустить?

Comment: @aepot код весь описан, в виде аргумента функции числа, которые выше

Comment: У вас в числах какие-то запятые и точки, что они значат?

Comment: @aepot разделители это просто как часть текста, как орфография предложения. На выходе функция возвращает текст, который был зашифрован в цифрах выше. Запятые и точки просто часть текста.

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы вы как-либо учитывали эти разделители при анализе. 4651 - это баг или фича? И вы так и не аказали, какое исключение выдает. Неужели так сложно?

Comment: @aepot точно, я если честно не особо придал этому значение. Спасибо